# UIButton TouchUpInside not always fired

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I have a DialPad with numbers where each one is a UIButton.

For each button, I handle 2 controlEvents:

- Touchdown: I generate a tone.
- TouchUpInside: I stop the tone.

The problem is that sometimes TouchUpInside isn't called. It only occurs when I play a tone during the TouchDown event.
If I comment my code which plays the ringtone, all the events are called as usual.

I add the control events like that:

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonUnpressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

the called selectors:

```
func buttonPressed(button: KeyboardButton) {
    print("IN")
    ACRAccount.generateTone(0x30)
}

func buttonUnpressed(button: KeyboardButton) {
    print("OUT")
    ACRAccount.stopGeneratingTone()
}
```

I used an external objective-c library to play the tone like this:

```
+ (void)generateTone:(int)tone
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        myExternalLibrary->audio->playTone((char)tone);
    });
}
```

Thanks for the help !

**EDIT 1**: It seems that `.TouchCancel` is called instead of `.TouchUpInside`.
This is due to my objective-C code because once commented, it works like a charm (without any call to `.TouchCancel`).
Any idea of the why ?

Comment: I guess you missed .TouchUpOutside event :)

Comment: So TouchUpInside only fires if you touched down inside first?

Comment: A TouchDragOutside event can also occur after a TouchDown event

Comment: I added TouchDragOutside and TouchUpOutside but they aren't called.

Comment: Wow I finally saw that this is the .TouchCancel event which is sometimes called instead of . TouchUpInside, any idea of why ?